# about the expression 'on someone's behalf'

Tags: word-usage, reading

I know the expression 'on (someone's) behalf' usually reads or is understood as 'instead of someone' but I'm wondering if it's possible for it to have a benefactive reading, that is, if it can be used to express one has been benefited by somebody else's action. Can anyone help me?

Comment: As in, using "I did that on Ivan's behalf" to mean "I did that to benefit Ivan"?

Comment: It's generally benefactive; you can't do something evil on behalf of the person it harms. It comes from the same root as _half_, meaning "(by the) side", so someone doing something on your behalf is at your side, or as we say it nowadays, they have your back.

Comment: Yes, @AndrewLeach Leach, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: @JohnLawler, I see your point, I mean  if the expression can ever be understood as benefactive without it having the meaning of someone doing something instead of you.

Comment: The way I see it, the question is asking for the exact opposite thing than @AndrewLeach's comment ("to have been benefited [sic] by somebody else's action" vs. "to benefit someone"). A clarification wouldn't hurt, even now that there's an accepted answer. In fact, on a more general note, any clarification should always go straight into the question, and never into the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At one time ***on*** behalf of and ***in*** behalf of meant different things:

> ***on*** behalf of X meant “in X’s name”, “representing X”
>   ***in*** behalf of X meant “in X’s interest”, “for X’s benefit”

About 1800, however, ***on*** behalf of began to be used in both senses; and, no doubt in consequence, ***in*** behalf of started to fade from use a couple of generations later.

[**Google Ngram:**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+behalf+of%2Con+behalf+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) [image]

In 1887 the OED called this a “recent use” which it regarded as “the loss of an important distinction”; but the language marches on, callously indifferent to the pain of even her most devoted followers. Today you may use the phrase in either sense.